# Missing tabs on taskbar

Tags: gnome-panel, panel, appearance, taskbar

I got shifted to a new workstation shortly. The system is using Ubuntu 11.04 - the Natty Narwhal - released in April 2011 and supported until October 2012. I found the bottom taskbar missing in it. I added it by clicking "new panel". I can see the Trash and the 4 workspaces,but i can't see the minimized tabs/windows on it. I searched for a fix but in vain. How to fix this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more widget to the panel, it's called `Window Selector`. It usually appears at the end of the list of widgets.

Comment: I know about it. It just displays an icon which when clicked shows a dropdown menu of active windows. But this is not i want. I want all tabs rather than a single icon

Comment: There a widget called `Window List` and another one called `Window Selector`. One of them is what you've already found and the other one is what you actually need.

Comment: It worked :) thank you. I didn't check that earlier.